# Issue with integer numbers when reading from existing workbook

Tags: python, excel, integer, openpyxl

I have an `.xlsx` file and am trying to read one column and dump it into a list. The values in the column are both `float` and `int`:

```
COLUMN B
72.3
78.34
80
82.4
83.49
84.34
...
```

This is the code I use to do the dumping:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#Reading the xlsx file in
wb=load_workbook(filename='Results.xlsx',use_iterators=True)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'Plot_2')

mylist=[]

for row in ws.iter_rows('B5:B104'):
    for cell in row:
        mylist.append(cell.value)
```

These are the values that I am returned:

```
In [1]: mylist
Out [1]:
[72.3,
 78.34,
 80L,
 82.4,
 83.49,
 84.34,
 ...
```

How can I make sure that my `80` is read in like an integer, without the `L` that is added to it, and why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
map(lambda x: int(x) if x%1==0 else x, mylist)
```

Comment: Where exactly should I add this line?

Comment: After reading in the excel sheet, you can do `mylist = map(lambda x: int(x) if x%1==0 else x, mylist)`

Comment: Is the conversion really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a common codebase for Python 2 and Python 3 we have decided to implement Python 3 types. While Python 2 has a special `long` type for large integers, there is no such type in Python 3. In order to be safe all integers are treated as `long`. This should have no side effects on your code.

Comment: So the `L` must stand for `long`. I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Yes, was this your question? When you print a variable in Python you will see its **representation** which might include information about the variable such as it's type.